# Implementing Classification Lookup and Forwarding

Tags: networking, router

I need to implement packet classification lookup and forwarding programitically. There are certain assumptions I have made while implementing it.

```
1.Each router has a single IP and interface of the router doesn't have individual IPs
2.Classification of packets is based on ethernet frame type field, 
  ip type field and tcp/udp destination and source port numbers.
3.Every node has a routing table (routers and end systems)
4.Each end machine should be directly connected to the router (no switches/hubs)
```

Is there any assumptions which are totally out of networking concepts or which need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Each router has a single IP and interface of the router doesn't have individual IPs

This isn't always true. In fact, it's probably false most of the time – IP addresses are almost always assigned to interfaces as far as I've seen. (Though I haven't had a chance to work with dedicated routers, only Linux & BSD-based ones.)

> 3.Every node has a routing table (routers and end systems)

Sounds correct, although end systems don't always show it.

> 4.Each end machine should be directly connected to the router (no switches/hubs)

Switches work at a lower layer; they're essentially invisible to IP... so as far as a router is concerned, this is true but I'm not sure why this should even matter?